# Flutter canvas, how to paint over the child widget?

Tags: flutter, canvas, flutter-layout, custom-painting

I am trying to draw red dots over the child textbox widget like this:

[image]

For that, I wrapped the child widget with `CustomPaint()` widget:

```
 return CustomPaint(
      painter: DotsPainter(), //draws red dots based on child's size
      child: child, //textbox
    );
```

But the result is this:

[image]

How to make CustomPainter "overlay" its child widget?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CustomPaint has 2 possible painters:

> When asked to paint, CustomPaint first asks its **painter** to paint on the current canvas, then it paints its child, and then, *after painting its child*, it asks its **foregroundPainter** to paint.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So if you move your painter to the [foregroundPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint/foregroundPainter.html) instead, it should work fine:

```
return CustomPaint(
  foregroundPainter: DotsPainter(), //draws red dots based on child's size
  child: child, //textbox
);
```